# Laravel file based session expiration throws exception

Tags: laravel, exception, session

Every morning I get the following error from a handful of users but not every user.
`fopen(/home/forge/mysite.com/storage/framework/sessions/lLNYGAJ55QF2J4elbDZ4H1N2GJ08iAwSsP8Wrv7a): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

One of the user I know uses firefox and has his privacy settings turned up pretty high but the others just seem to be random users.

My gut is telling me that the session is expiring on the server before it expires on the client. since most users don't generate this error every day.

My question is what are the knobs I need to tweak to make sure I shouldn't see this message in the logs any more? Or, if I'm wrong about my assumptions, how can I track this down?